# Get Facebook space name PHP

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, sdk

Is there a way to get the facebook namespace starting from appid and secret key?

I need this information because of this:

```
$request = $this->CI->facebook->api('/me/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION,'POST',array(
    $object_type => $url
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are logged in as the app owner, most app settings can be read and written to just by getting/posting with the APP ID:

```
$request = $this->CI->facebook->api('/APP_ID/?fields=namespace');
$namespace = $request['namespace'];
```

Some of those fields (like namespace) are also public and do not even require an access token to view.

Comment: Note that if your app is not live (under Status & Review) you will get `{"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the namespace by querying the app for the field `namespace`, application namespace seem to be public, so you only need the application id to get it.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=117782344904363%3Ffields%3Dnamespace